# SQL Query - Change date format in query to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What I'm trying to achieve is fairly straight forward, to get one date format to another;

From This: `Jan 30 2013 12:00:00:000AM`
To This: `DD/MM/YYYY` or in this case `30/01/2013`

However, when it's the 1st to the 9th of the month the date format is missing a zero and there is two spaces, as shown;

```
Jul  3 2014 12:00:00:000AM
```

I've hunted round for a solution but without success, the format of the date is unusual and varies depending on the day of the month however this format is generated by an internal system and can't be changed. Would I then have to pattern match in order to change the format? How would I go about doing this?

An example of part of the query is this;

```
SELECT
PREFIX_TableName.ColumnName1 AS Name,
PREFIX_TableName.ColumnName2 AS E-Mail,
PREFIX_TableName.ColumnName3 AS TransactionDate,
PREFIX_TableName.ColumnName4 AS OrderNumber,
...
```

The line to be edited is this `PREFIX_TableName.ColumnName3 AS TransactionDate,`

Comment: post the query you have tried

Comment: Is it MySql or Sql-Server? You have tagged both

Comment: Which datatype does your column have? Is it a Datetime or a Varchar?

Comment: It's usually best to keep everything in SQL Server in `datetime` (or `datetime2`) types, and only do any string formatting a lot closer to the user.

Comment: It's an MSSQL query via OPENQUERY to an ADP KCML database

Comment: Check out this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx . There are codes for converting your datetimes to all kind of different string represantation

Answer (score 29):

If DB is **SQL Server** then

```
select Convert(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,YourDateColumn,106),103)
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. I would have expected that you'd have to use 109 as the input datetime style, although 106 seems to work just fine. In either case, SQL Server interprets `Jul  3 2014 12:00:00:000AM` correctly - even if there's an additional space between the month and the date. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx for more conversion options.

Answer (score 6):

If I understood your question, try something like this

```
declare @dd varchar(50)='Jan 30 2013 12:00:00:000AM'

Select convert(varchar,(CONVERT(date,@dd,103)),103)
```

***Update***

```
SELECT
PREFIX_TableName.ColumnName1 AS Name,
PREFIX_TableName.ColumnName2 AS E-Mail,
convert(varchar,(CONVERT(date,PREFIX_TableName.ColumnName3,103)),103) AS TransactionDate,
PREFIX_TableName.ColumnName4 AS OrderNumber
```

Comment: I've now posted the relevant part of the query in the description above.

Comment: I've given it a test and the query doesn't run.

Comment: @Matt : What is the error you have. Just try selecting the date column `SELECT convert(varchar,(CONVERT(date,PREFIX_TableName.ColumnName3,103)),103) AS TransactionDate  FROM  PREFIX_TableName`

Comment: syntax error in: ... PREFIX_TableName.ColumnName3, >>> convert <<< (varchar,(CONVERT(date,PREFIX_TableName.ColumnName3,103)),103)...

Comment: What is the column data type?

Comment: I've run the single select and that throws a syntax error too. I'm using SQL but further down the line it's using an ODBC connection to communicate with the KCML database

Answer (score 4):

If you have a Date (or Datetime) column, look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datecolumn,'%d/%m/%Y') FROM ...
```

Should do the job for MySQL, for SqlServer I'm sure there is an analog function.
If you have a VARCHAR column, you might have at first to convert it to a date, see `STR_TO_DATE` for MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(11),Getdate(),105)
```

Comment: Hey how can i specify which column i want to convert ?

Comment: @PrinceArora you just need to replace your column with Getdate() functions

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx. Lists all formats needed.
In this case select Convert(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,YourDateColumn,106),103)
change 103 to 104 id you need dd.mm.yyyy