# extract the month and the year in this format: "mm-yyyy" along with all columns

Tags: mysql

I have a field start in my databse from the type date. I want to extract the month and the year in this format: mm-yyyy, I also need all other columns.

I tried this:

```
$query='SELECT *, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, start), 0) AS [start] FROM ...
```

according to 
[Getting only Month and Year from SQL DATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781946/getting-only-month-and-year-from-sql-date)

but it doesn't work. Error:

```
Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'"
```

Also I'm not sure how to continue afterwards.  found this:
[SQL Query - Change date format in query to DD/MM/YYYY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565980/sql-query-change-date-format-in-query-to-dd-mm-yyyy)

So my guess would be:

```
Convert(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,DATEADD(MONTH, (DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, start), 0) AS [start]),106),103)
```

but then I still have the days.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use a SQL Server solution but if your tag is accurate, you're on MySQL. Date/time functions are one area where database systems vary a *lot* so even when they have functions of the same name, there's no guarantee that they do the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(start, '%m-%Y') FROM ...;
```

Comment: That's the best version on the other ones you still have to add a '0', because the format is m-yyyy and also it interferres with the ORDER BY at the end of my query (which is my fault, that I didn't mention it).THX

Comment: @AndiGiga, you don't have to add a '0'. Try `SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2014-1-2', '%m-%Y')`. It'll return `01-2014`.

Comment: I meant on the other solutions you have to do that. Sorry for the confusion. Your solution is perfect.

Comment: A different twist to this could be `SELECT DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(start, '%Y-%m')) FROM ...`. This way you can obtain all the relevant year-month combinations.

Answer (score 0):

You are using SQL-Server syntax for your MySQL installation. That won't work. Every DB engine has a slightly different syntax and functions. Use

```
SELECT *, year(start), month(start)
from your_table
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this logic as well:-

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(MONTH(start), '-',  YEAR(start)) AS START
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: It doesn't give the `mm-yyyy` format. You will have something like `1-2014` instead of `01-2014`.